# Почему не устанавливается цвет CardVIew в RecyclerView?

Tags: android, kotlin, recyclerview, cardview

У `CardView` никак не устанавливается цвет программно. `CardView` является элементом `RecyclerView`.

`onBindViewHolder`:

```
override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        when (holder) {
            is TimerViewHolder -> {
                holder.bind(items[position])
            }
        }
    }
```

`class` in `Adapter`:

```
class TimerViewHolder
constructor(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    private val cardView: CardView = itemView.card_view
    private val colors: ArrayList<Int> = arrayListOf(
        R.color.timer_blue,
        R.color.timer_green,
        R.color.timer_orange,
        R.color.timer_purple,
        R.color.timer_red
    )
    
    fun bind(timer: Timer) {
        cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(colors[(0 until colors.size).random()]) // не работает
    }
}
```

Comment: `private val cardView: CardView = itemView.card_view` мне кажется, что вот это должно выглядеть как-то так: `private val cardView: CardView; init { cardView = view.findViewById(R.id.your_view_id)` если без viewBinding

Comment: @Pentiux Ваш вариант конечно тоже работает, но мой вариант тоже захватывает нужный `CardView`, поэтому в этом проблемы нет.

Comment: R.color.timer_blue - colorId а не сам Color? context.resources.getColor(R.color.color_id, context.activity.theme) - по памяти точно не помню обращения, не в IDE

Comment: Да, `itemView.context.getColor(R.color.timer_blue)` помогло. Добавьте ответ, чтобы я отметил его решением.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Из комментариев:
`R.color.timer_blue` - colorId а не сам Color? `context.resources.getColor(R.color.color_id, context.activity.theme)` - по памяти точно не помню обращения, не в IDE – Pentiux

Да, `itemView.context.getColor(R.color.timer_blue)` помогло.  – Dewerro

На всякий: этот метот, насколько я помню, deprecated. Так что стоит использовать метод с темой, просто дописать получение темы, как в моем сообщении.